# Getting the exact amount of spaces between tables

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get an exact amount of spaces between 2 tables. I tried br, but it takes up around 10 pixels of spaces between the 2 tables. Instead of having 10 pixels of spaces between the tables, I would like to have 5. Is that doable? Thanks.

**test.php**

```
<table border = '1'>

<tr><td>Hello</td></tr>

</table>

<br>

<table border = '1'>

<tr><td>Hello</td></tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `<br/>` from html and update css like following

```
table:first-child {
 margin-bottom : 5px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put first table inside the div with margin bottom as big as you want. Like this:

```
<div style="margin-bottom:5px">
<table>...</table>
</div>
```